# How to Call Rest API with header and body for e2e protractor testing?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, azure-devops-rest-api

testcase for this using e2e protractor testing

```
it('Should reach testsite', done => {
           request('https://sbx-office-api.b2bcloud.com/rmi/v1/books/list?type=fetchall' + '/authorize/authenticate')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*').set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36')
            .set('Authorization', 'token')

            .end(function (error, body) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('error:', error);
                } else {
                    console.log('body:', body);
                }
            });

        });
```

e2e protractor testing

Answer (score 0):

```html
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://sbx-office-api.b2bcloud.com/rmi/v1/books/list?type=fetchall',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlFrTTFRemt6UlVJNE5UazNSVVJGTUVVNU5rTXlNVVpFT0RJek5EQTNPRFkyTVVaRVFrVXdSZyJ9.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.D5MoBVJ2lWZ7b3FCZtMQkmdMxJot8SCR1-Oso-wponPtF2y6kLxKK5dUftI_yzydvaJsZ9mwjVvZIAHESlrwkjVizYGXTFchjasT81hMZtJgt6iW8sA7Nu5qx7MVsc2z7UAS0mGhV2a_NEvZaYQ1A0dC19wG2A6bNJIMNEy46oJXlUe8nxb1ezkh4CkO3jUnVIPBo4rney_uwcXj-wc5hiE3a6m7jeHphyy70zDBFD_YRiizZaXzI-LTPGvhuRb7UtfcZuOomQqOuH6xebaoe3OzX9aA7CfWCHIJDhjQJwC-5BR5HQ9k7FCae3L4pWfmUVUOTZEFViJtxazLxOjM_w',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36'
    },
    body: '{ "headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null}}'
};


it('Should reach testsite', done => {

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error);
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
            console.log('body:', body);
            done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By importing one of node library which can make http calls. EG supertest
Protractor is not meant for making external http/https request.